# How to improve the quality of a video?

Tags: video

Is it possible to enhance the quality of videos such as avi, mp4, xvid, flv, etc. 
Like there are filters for images such as hq2x, etc are there also filters for videos?

Suppose I have a 3gp video with 176x144 is there something that can increase its size to 320x240 while improving its video quality?

Comment: [Here's a demonstration of the technology OP is looking for](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KUFkb0d1kbU)

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to add information that's not there.

You are approximately doubling the dimensions of each frame so you will need to add pixels in between each of the existing ones. The best you can hope for is to interpolate the colour - this will give you a smooth image, but it will be more blurred than the original.

Comment: Yup, there's not much they can do. See this recent Q: [Which resize algorithm to choose for videos?](http://superuser.com/questions/375718/which-resize-algorithm-to-choose-for-videos/375726#375726)

Comment: hq2x guesses the pixel while enlarging an image and gives a good quality. So I thought may be such thing might be existing for videos. Or may be we can apply this hq2x filter on frames of videos?

Comment: @ZealKaiser - you could apply this to each frame of the video I suppose, but a guess is still a guess.

Comment: @ZealKaiser There are some algorithms explained in the question I linked to above. Some are better, some are worse. You can't really optimize such filters like you can do for pixel data, and bicubic or bilinear filtering is probably the best you can do. Look into what various tools offer, for example [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

Comment: aah the dreadful 3gp videos, even worse than VHS lol
hmm, you can try converting them to png and use something like photoshop the improve them, other than that there isnt that much to do with so low quality files

Answer (score 4):

All the "image enhancement" stuff in movies doesn't actually work; When you convert, there's only two options: to stay the same quality or get worse. Like the other answer says, you cannot add pixels that aren't there in the original file. When you hear talk of "master" tracks, what happens is the producer makes the original file in extremely high quality, usually they down-convert to a normal resolution and then distribute it.

On a side note, think of what this could mean. We could download small movies, then upconvert them to massive resolutions.

Comment: I know we cant add pixels but we can create an algorithm which guesses a pixel between two pixels by analysing them. We cannot get the same quality but then we can get a better quality then the small video.

Comment: That's what ChrisF talked about with interpolation. It guesses what color the pixel should be, but mostly just achieves a blurred image, as also stated by ChrisF.